# Add column to dataframe with the number of times a specific value appeared: starting from 1, 2 ... n

Tags: r, dataframe

There have been many similar type of questions, but all those are about counting the total amount of times a value appears in a column. I want to add a column that increments each time when a specific value appears in another column:

From 1, 2, 3 ... n.

Example df:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), val = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1))
```

In this example, I just want an extra column "count" that adds 1 whenever a 1 (or other supplied value) appears in the "val" column. The resulting dataframe should look like:

```
> df
   id val count
1   1   0     0
2   2   0     0
3   3   1     1 
4   4   0     0
5   5   1     2
6   6   0     0
7   7   0     0
8   8   1     3
9   9   1     4
10 10   1     5
```

Comment: `df$val * cumsum(df$val)`?

Comment: That adds just 1 because the value in the original dataframe is 1. In other dataframes i will be using these values are different. I can divide it two times by the val value, but it's not very clean

Comment: `df <- df %>%
 mutate(count = case_when(val!=0 ~ cumsum(val),
                           val==0 | is.na(val) ~ 0))`  
in that case (using the tidyverse) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of the sceanario mentioned in comments above, Let's take a different example and suppose you want a count whenever val is `1`

```r
df
   id val count
1   1   0     0
2   2   0     0
3   3   1     1
4   4   2     0
5   5   1     2
6   6   0     0
7   7   2     0
8   8   1     3
9   9   1     4
10 10   1     5

df$count <- (df$val == 1) * cumsum(df$val == 1)
df
#>    id val count
#> 1   1   0     0
#> 2   2   0     0
#> 3   3   1     1
#> 4   4   2     0
#> 5   5   1     2
#> 6   6   0     0
#> 7   7   2     0
#> 8   8   1     3
#> 9   9   1     4
#> 10 10   1     5
```

Needless to say you'll need to replace `1` with your desired value in both places above

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not oppose for loops this works.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), val = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1))
temp<-c(0)

for (i in 1:length(df$val)){
   if (df$val[i]){
  temp<-temp+1
  df$count[i]<-temp
  } else {
   df$count[i]<-0
  }
}

df

 id val count
1   1   0     0
2   2   0     0
3   3   1     1
4   4   0     0
5   5   1     2
6   6   0     0
7   7   0     0
8   8   1     3
9   9   1     4
10 10   1     5
```